# If $f, g \in L^+$, then $\int f - g = \int f - \int g$?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Given a measure space $(X, M, \mu)$, let $L^+$ be the set of all measurable functions from $X$ to $[0, \infty]$.  If $f, g \in L^+$, with $f \ge g$ is it true that
$$\int (f - g) d\mu = \int f d\mu - \int g d\mu$$

Comment: $X=\Bbb R$ and $f=g=e^x$? This set results in the indeterminate $\infty - \infty$.